# Rational function must have polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

In Oscar Fernandez' *Everyday Calculus*, he refers to this equation as a *rational function*:
$$r(V) = k{\sqrt{P_0l} \over V}.$$
Don't both the numerator and denominator have to be polynomials to be called a *rational function*? Is he, maybe, calling it this simply because it contains a ratio of $ \sqrt{P_0l} $ over $ V $?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Fernandez is calling this a rational function, because the numerator and denominator are both polynomials in $V$.

Remember that a polynomail of degree $n$ in $V$ is just an expression of the form:$$\alpha_0+\alpha_1V+\alpha_2V^2+\alpha_3V^3+\ldots+\alpha_nV^n.$$

So if we choose $\alpha_0=k\sqrt{P_0 l}$ and $\alpha_i=0$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, then we see that $k\sqrt{P_0 l}$ is a polynomial in $V$ of degree $0$.

Likwise we can choose $\alpha_0=0$, $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_i=0$, for $i=2,3,\ldots,n$, and we  see that $V$ is a polynomial in $V$ of degree $1$.

So the expresion $k\frac{\sqrt{P_0l}}{V}$ is a rational function indeed.